# Java Api for vt100 telnet neaded

Tags: java, networking, query-string, connection-string

I have problem to solve. there is vt100 telnet connected device which i have to control. The problem is that the devices telnet server shows advanced menus, witch is controlled with up and down buttons. Do someone can advice some JAVA api to solve this situation. Thank YOU in advance.

Sincerely
yours Vaginn

Comment: By the way, i forgot to tell. that my java program uses telnet connection to speak to vt100 server. I do not need to emulate any menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious candidate would be JCurses: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/
but I have to admit that I did not used this